# How to remove the glass globe to clean it?

Tags: house

I want to clean this glass globe but I have no idea about how to remove it.
Any suggestions?
[image: The image containing the bulbs]

Comment: I would try to slide the globe off one spike/rod then wiggle/waggle it off the others.  Getting it back on should be just as much fun.

Comment: Maybe at least 1 of the 3 metal rods supporting each globe unscrew from the central shaft? Unscrew it, then the globe might be wiggle/waggled off, as crip659 suggestes.

Comment: Is it possible that the pins hinge *upwards* ? That is, you lift the globe (pushing the support down into it), and the pins disengage before the angle becomes too great or the bulb reaches the bottom of the globe ?

Comment: @crip659 That's more likely to result in a broken globe than a safely removed one, since the distance between the rods changes (rapidly) the further you get from the equilibrium position.

Comment: There has to be an instruction leaflet somewhere on the Internet showing how to fit/change a bulb in this sort of cover...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Attempt to unscrew the rods.

There's actually a high likelihood that all three rods will unscrew, meaning you can easily remove any two of them, then slide the globe off the third rod. You'll want to leave one screwed in place to help reduce the chance of dropping the globe when removing and reinstalling.

It was probably shipped with none of the horizontal rods installed to make the packaging easier at the factory.

Comment: FWIW, I used Google Lens and found what seem to be [installation instructions](https://www.verlichting.be/nl/attachment/fiche/download/key/NzY0OTQtc29hcC1wZW5kYW50LWV1LnBkZg==) for the type of lamp the OP has, and they indeed confirm that the rods screw in (and out). However, either the OP has a knockoff version (which is plausible, they seem to be made in China and sold under lots of different names) or it's been installed incorrectly, since the OP's lamps seem to be missing the plastic grommets that should go in the holes in the glass before the rods are pushed through them and screwed in.